# bash scripting: search Java STDOUT for a variable

Tags: java, linux, bash, stdout

When I run myTest.jar, it outputs alot of information in STDOUT (not in a file) and I am trying to read/search that file for a specific string to put as a variable in my bash script.

java stdout:

```
line 1 info............ 

line 2 info........... 

.... 

...

Successful    (either 'Successful' or 'Failed')
```

How do I search for, in bash, the last line in the stdout or for ('Successful' or 'Failed') without redirecting the stdout to a file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: output could be sent to both a file and stdout simultaneously, then you could grep the file (output would still be displayed on screen). would this work for your needs?

Comment: Pipe the output to a `tail --lines=1` command?  I'm not sure if that will give you what you need.

Comment: Its sorta like "that other guy" is saying except the "Successful" or "Failed" doesn't depend on if the jar fails or not, its just an overall status of my report that I write depending on the results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a good way of checking for success or failure.

You should instead rewrite `myTest.jar` to use `System.exit(0)` on success and `System.exit(1)` (or higher) on error. If the program is well written, it will already do this.

You can then check for success or failure in bash using e.g.

```
if java -jar mytest.jar 
then
  echo "The command succeeded :D"
else
  echo "The command failed :("
fi
```

All UNIX programs work this way, and you should make sure that `myTest.jar` is no exception.

Comment: "Successful" or "Failed" doesn't depend on if the jar fails or not, its just an overall status of my report that I write depending on the results.  Would what your saying achieve the same thing basically?

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you would need to redirect `stdout` to a file and then cat/vim/search that file. Bash doesn't save the output of commands on its own.

Alternatively, you could use a program like `screen` that allows you to save a transcript of your session to a file. You would get the output of everything and the command lines though.

Answer (score 0):

for future users, I used "that other guys' " method with some minor adjustments:

1) the exit code and what your doing have to be right after the running jar, wouldn't work for me in other segments

2) I read the exit code I was receiving and made an if loop for my conditions (0-2) exit code was given in java

3) piece of my bash code

```
EXIT_CODE=$?
echo Exit code: $EXIT_CODE

if [ $EXIT_CODE = "0" ]
then
    ...............do something
elif [$EXIT_CODE = "1"]
then
    ...............do something
else
    ...............do something
fi
```